# Griffon integration to NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, groovy, griffon

I have been researching on integration of griffon to NetBeans IDE but all I get online and on this platform has not solved my problem.I keep getting this error

The plugin Groovy Support is requested in implementation version 201112071828.

```
  The following plugins are affected:       
   groovy.griffon       
   groovy.griffonproject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Griffon 2.x projects are regular Gradle (or Maven) projects, as such you do not require a Griffon specific plugin in NetBeans. See http://griffon-framework.org/tutorials/1_getting_started.html#_tutorial_1_4 for more information.

There is a Griffon plugin for NetBeans though, it was designed to work with Griffon 1.x. Both Griffon 1.x and the Griffon NetBeans plugin are no longer maintained and their usage is discouraged.